# 80s cartoon that had foes that looked like ant or scorpion aliens and rode cycled vehicles

Tags: story-identification, cartoon

I'm looking to identify this 1980s cartoon that had a gang of foes. They had cycled vehicles and looked like ants or scorpions from an alien race (I don’t know exactly).

Comment: By "they had cycled vehicles and looked like ants or scorpions from an alien race", are you referring to the "gang of foes" or to the protagonists? (I’m asking to make sure your question is worded properly.)

Answer (score 8):

Perhaps you're recalling *[Jayce and the Wheeled Warriors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jayce_and_the_Wheeled_Warriors)* (1985)

> The show featured two duelling forces. The heroes are humans called the Lightning League who drive white and silver vehicles with assorted weaponry led by a teenager named Jayce. The villains are organic plant-based creatures called the Monster Minds who travel via large green organic vines, which can grow in and across interstellar space, and sprout seeds that grow rapidly into further Monster Minds. They are led by the very first of the Monster Minds, Saw Boss.
>
> [image: scorpion esque vehicle]

Comment: OP mentioned the villians. You might want to show some pics of those instead; https://jayce.fandom.com/wiki/Gun_Grinner / https://jayce.fandom.com/wiki/Terror_Tank /  https://jayce.fandom.com/wiki/KO_Kruiser etc

Answer (score 2):

I had a friend with the same memory. We figured out it was a cartoon called ***[InseKtorS](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0122349/)*** (1994).

They fought off the enemy with musical colour guns.

> The comic insect fight between Good and Evil. The Verygreens love
> sunlight, bright colours and hilarity. The Kruds prefer shadows and
> dull colours, and spend all their time plotting to overthrow the
> Verygreens - always coming up with gadgets, machines and crazy plots
> that never quite work.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Can you include some screenshots to help make the identification?